# Noob questions - login to websites and MacOS

Tags: pi-2, noobs, setup, script, web-browsers

Why does my Raspberry Pi 2 identify on websites as MAC OSX? (which prevents me from downloading the correct versions of software/debian?)??

Why can't I login to ANY website (Google, etc.)?  Are there JS limitations in the stock browser (epiphany) that prevent this?

Comment: The browser is based on Webkit, hence it is often identified as OSX. This won't have any consequences as you won't be able to find any software suitable for running on the Pi, because, apart from the Foundation or programs specifically designed to run on the Pi there is almost no downloadable software.

Comment: Even if it did identify as linux and there are linux binaries available of whatever you want, those will be for x86(-86) computers (e.g, normal desktops and laptops) and will not work on the pi.  If you want to install third party software not available in the Raspbian repos via `apt`, they will need to have source packages available so you can built them yourself (a whole separate question) or else an ARM port (which may or may not work).

Answer (score 2):

When you visit a website part of the info your browser sends to the webserver is the user-agent header. You can view the user-agent header using this [webpage](http://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/). Assuming you are using the default browser it should look like this:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; ARM Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/538.15 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Safari/538.15 Version/6.0 Raspbian/8.0 (1:3.8.2.0-0rpi27rpi1g)
>   Epiphany/3.8.2

As you can see it claims to be the Mozilla browser running on Mac, and confusingly also Safari.

You can spoof this header, but that is usually not needed. Download pages usually include a small link to other versions. However, as millways points out you won't find much software available for the Pi outside the regular repositories.

You can read more about the user-agent header on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent).